How to calculate interest for InterestBearingConfig extension without sending a transaction?
Currently, it seems like to calculating the accrued interest for a mint account with the InterestBearingConfig extension requires sending a transaction with the AmountToUiAmount instruction.
/**
 * Construct a AmountToUiAmount instruction
 *
 * @param mint         Public key of the mint
 * @param amount       Amount of tokens to be converted to UiAmount
 * @param programId    SPL Token program account
 *
 * @return Instruction to add to a transaction
 */
export function createAmountToUiAmountInstruction(
    mint: PublicKey,
    amount: number | bigint,
    programId = TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID
): TransactionInstruction {
    const keys = [{ pubkey: mint, isSigner: false, isWritable: false }];

    const data = Buffer.alloc(amountToUiAmountInstructionData.span);
    amountToUiAmountInstructionData.encode(
        {
            instruction: TokenInstruction.AmountToUiAmount,
            amount: BigInt(amount),
        },
        data
    );

    return new TransactionInstruction({ keys, programId, data });
}

Is there a way to calculate the interest without sending a transaction? For example, to just display on a UI.

It looks like the amountToUiAmount helper function simulates the transaction instead of sending one.
export async function amountToUiAmount(
    connection: Connection,
    payer: Signer,
    mint: PublicKey,
    amount: number | bigint,
    programId = TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID
): Promise<string | TransactionError | null> {
    const transaction = new Transaction().add(createAmountToUiAmountInstruction(mint, amount, programId));
    const { returnData, err } = (await connection.simulateTransaction(transaction, [payer], false)).value;
    if (returnData?.data) {
        return Buffer.from(returnData.data[0], returnData.data[1]).toString('utf-8');
    }
    return err;
}


This is correct. We've been meaning to write a function to do this on the JS side https://github.com/solana-labs/solana-program-library/issues/3265 but no one's done it yet
